# How to set Base URL for Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have my laravel project and vuejs project in different folders.

Laravel url is : localhost:8000
Vuejs Url is: localhost:8080

So if i want to load images saved on the laravel project i need to include the laravel project url in my vuejs project like this

```
<img class="main-profile" :src="getProfilePhoto()" alt="">
```

```
methods: {
        getProfilePhoto(){
            return "http://localhost:8000/img/profile/"+ this.form.profilePicture;
        }
```

This above shows the image

But i get this error `localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:8000/img/profile/ 404 (Not Found)` in my chrome console

I did this

```
<img class="main-profile" :src='"http://localhost:8000/img/profile/"+this.form.profilePicture' alt="">
```

but i still get error.

The laravel project and vuejs project are in different directory. how can i solve the 404 Error `127.0.0.1/:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/profile/ 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: If you access directly the url, does it shows the image?

Comment: Yeah it does but why does it show 404 in chrome console?

Comment: Even after concatenating ```<img class="main-profile" :src="'http://localhost:8000/img/profile/'+this.form.profilePicture" alt="">```